# Center the TextView in android?

Tags: android, layout, textview

How to center the TextView in Android?

This is what happens:
[image: left-aligned text]

This is what I want:
[image: centered text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following to your textview layout: gravity="center_horizontal"